# Toggle 'display:none' with JavaScript after transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a dropdown menu for mobile devices with animation so when the transition ends, it needs to be display:none. Here's what I've done:

```js
const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menuButton')
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav')

function menuToggle() {
    if (navMenu.classList.contains('navDisplay')) {
        navMenu.classList.remove('navShow')
        setTimeout(() => {
            navMenu.classList.remove('navDisplay')  
        }, 300)     
    } else {
        navMenu.classList.add('navDisplay') 
        setTimeout(() => {
            navMenu.classList.add('navShow')
        }, 0) 
    }
}

menuButton.addEventListener('click', menuToggle)
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #e8e8e8;
}

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

h2 {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

a {
    transition: all.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all.3s ease;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #777777;
}

/*--------------NAV BAR------------*/

header {
    background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.95);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menuButton {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 65px;
    margin: 10 30px;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', sans-serif;
    line-height: 65px;
}


    nav div ul {
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    nav div ul li {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    
    nav {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .nav {
        display: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;
        transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .orderButton {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .logo {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .menuButton {
        display: block;
    }

    .navShow {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .navDisplay {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<header>
<div class="menuButton">&#9776;</div>
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><p class="logo">LOGO</p></a>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><div class="orderButton">ELEMENT1</div></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ELEMENT2</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">ELM3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      </header>
```

So, the menu has `display:none` and `height:0` by default. The click event listener triggers function that checks if menu is displayed or not and adds or removes respective classes (the display class removes after the transition ends with the help of timeout 400ms). Is there any more beautiful or less code solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You are making it way more complex. You don't need to have a `display:none` and a `height:0`. `height:0` with `overflow:hidden` will do the job. If you wanna show the links after the menu gets its height with a delay, you could use `opacity`. That and using the `toggle` function will make it as simple as this:

```js
const menuButton = document.querySelector(".menuButton");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav");

function menuToggle() {
   navMenu.classList.toggle("navShow");
}

menuButton.addEventListener("click", menuToggle);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

h2 {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

a {
  transition: all.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all.3s ease;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #777777;
}

/*--------------NAV BAR------------*/

header {
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.95);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menuButton {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin: 10 30px;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", sans-serif;
  line-height: 65px;
}

nav div ul {
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav div ul li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  opacity:0;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out,opacity 300ms 400ms ease-in-out;

}

.orderButton {
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.menuButton {
  display: block;
}

.navShow {
   opacity:1;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menuButton">&#9776;</div>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">
      <p class="logo">LOGO</p>
    </a>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="orderButton">ELEMENT1</div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ELEMENT2</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">ELM3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can. But if I add paddings...?

Comment: paddings on what ?

Comment: You could use this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/BamOPwO) link of your example to show me what you are talking about.

Comment: Making objects minimised to 0 is considered as a bad practice.

Comment: Just add paddings to class .nav and see how menu is still visible even if height: 0

Comment: https://codepen.io/plzthrko-the-styleful/pen/bGYxjyy here's an example with paddings. I also added white borders for better visualisation.

Comment: I see. But do you need that padding ?

Comment: I don't need EXACTLY that padding. But I have some cases in my project where I do need a padding, but I won't paste code because it's too big and bloated.

Comment: I see. If you expect another solution I am gonna delete my answer.

Comment: No, the answer is ok, but in that particular situation it is not so good. I will look and wait for another answers.